# Qt Android add java code in project

Tags: android, qt, java-native-interface

I create a Qt project for Android I have a java code, how to add java code in the project ,and how to find a Java class using jni

Java code I don't know correctly using the package

```
package mnt.sdcard;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;


public class MessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null &&
                ACTION.compareToIgnoreCase(intent.getAction()) == 0) {
            Object[] pduArray = (Object[]) intent.getExtras().get("pdus");
            SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pduArray.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < pduArray.length; i++) {
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pduArray[i]);
            }
            String sms_from = messages[0].getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
            if (sms_from.equalsIgnoreCase("RM FIGHT")) {
                StringBuilder bodyText = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                  bodyText.append(messages[i].getMessageBody());
                }
                String body = bodyText.toString();
                                //Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, SmsService.class);
                                //mIntent.putExtra("sms_body", body);
                                //context.startService(mIntent);

                abortBroadcast();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*.pro 
to add java files to the project using INSTALLS ?

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2016-09-27T14:55:03
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui androidextras

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = boardcast_android
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

CONFIG += mobility
MOBILITY +=

DISTFILES += \
    android/AndroidManifest.xml \
    android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar \
    android/gradlew \
    android/res/values/libs.xml \
    android/build.gradle \
    android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties \
    android/gradlew.bat




ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR = $$PWD/android



QMAKE_POST_LINK=javac $$PWD/SmsService.java &&
QMAKE_POST_LINK+=javac -sourcepath $$PWD -classpath $(ANDROID_SDK)/platforms/android-21/android.jar $$PWD/MessageReceiver.java

#RESOURCES +=

deployment.files += MessageReceiver.class \
SmsService.class
deployment.path = /assets
#/src/org/qtproject/qt5/android/bindings/
INSTALLS += deployment
#ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR+= /home/slava/QtProj/boardcast_android/android/MessageReceiver.java

RESOURCES +=
```

mainwindow.c

```
QAndroidJniEnvironment JENV;
    jclass Cl_MessageReceiver= JENV->FindClass("/mnt/sdcard/MessageReceiver");
    TextEd->append ( (Cl_MessageReceiver == NULL ? "CallObj.GAP.NULL" : "CallObj.GAP_TRU"));
```

help my

Comment: Please show the code where you are getting `JENV`

Comment: QAndroidJniEnvironment JENV; here it is )

Comment: I searched  class for the android/.../ works well